# Batchable & Schedulable class has cyclomatic complexity of 48

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, pmd

**Background**

I have a class which implements `Database.Batchable<Sobject>` and `Schedulable` and when I run PMD I get this problem:

> The class 'MyClassBatchJob' has a total cyclomatic complexity of 48 (highest 5).

**Questions**

1. How is the Apex cyclomatic complexity calculated?
2. How should I approach Batchable & Schedulable classes to reduce cyclomatic complexity?

Comment: Bear in mind that such metrics are great for drawing attention to parts of your code base that might benefit from some refactoring. The real metric though is more subjective and is whether others can easily and safely understand and modify the code in the future. That has multiple aspects including using good naming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Roughly speaking, too many branching constructs (`if`, `for`, etc.) in a single method. It's usually a sign that your methods could be broken down into more readable chunks.

Their complete definition:

> The complexity of methods directly affects maintenance costs and
>   readability. Concentrating too much decisional logic in a single
>   method makes its behaviour hard to read and change.
>
> Cyclomatic complexity assesses the complexity of a method by counting
>   the number of decision points in a method, plus one for the method
>   entry. Decision points are places where the control flow jumps to
>   another place in the program. As such, they include all control flow
>   statements, such as ‘if’, ‘while’, ‘for’, and ‘case’.
>
> Generally, numbers ranging from 1-4 denote low complexity, 5-7 denote
>   moderate complexity, 8-10 denote high complexity, and 11+ is very high
>   complexity. By default, this rule reports methods with a complexity >=
>   10. Additionnally, classes with many methods of moderate complexity get reported as well once the total of their methods’ complexities
>   reaches 40, even if none of the methods was directly reported.
>
> Reported methods should be broken down into several smaller methods.
>   Reported classes should probably be broken down into subcomponents.

https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.7.0/pmd_rules_apex_design.html#cyclomaticcomplexity

**Edit**

Re-reading your message, it looks like it's probably that the class has too many methods and the total is too high, rather than any particular method being very bad. So, you should probably break the class into a few classes, each of which only does one thing. If you post your code (maybe as a separate question on how to decompose the class), you may be able to get specific help on doing that.